# id_element not update on rails3-jquery-autocomplete

Tags: ruby-on-rails

It's work fine if I not add option delimiter" => ','

but 'id_element' not update if I added delimiter" => ',' option

```
<%= hidden_field_tag "to_provider_ids" %>
<%= autocomplete_field_tag 'to', '', autocomplete_provider_source_agency_name_users_path, "data-delimiter" => ',',, :id_element => '#to_provider_ids' %>
```

please help me solved this problem. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use 'railsAutocomplete.select' event to update id.

```
$('#my_autocomplete_field').bind('railsAutocomplete.select', function(event, data){
  /* Do something here */
  alert(data.item.id);
});
```